# Why am I stuck on the loading screen?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

When executing in browser and trying to signup, I am stuck on the react-loading screen. The goal is to add the user details being passed in the text fields to be inserted into the firebase authentication and storage collection. The same thing is also happening in the sign in component. It seems to be an issue with firebase but I am not sure exactly what it is.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import LoginString from '../../loginstrings';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");

class SignUp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state ={
            isLoading: false,
            email: "",
            password: "",
            name:""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
   
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }
    async handleSubmit(event){
        const {name,password,email} = this.state;
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({isLoading: true})
        try {
            const auth = getAuth();
            const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            userCredential.then(async result => {
                await firebase.firestore().collection('users')
                .add({
                    name,
                    id:result.user.uid,
                    email,
                    password,
                    URL:'',
                    description:''
                })
                .then((docRef)=>{
                        localStorage.setItem(LoginString.FirebaseDocumentId, docRef.id);
                        localStorage.setItem(LoginString.ID, result.user.uid);
                        localStorage.setItem(LoginString.name, name);
                        localStorage.setItem(LoginString.email, email);
                        localStorage.setItem(LoginString.PhotoURL, "");
                        localStorage.setItem(LoginString.Description, "");
                        this.setState({isLoading: false});
                        this.props.history.push('/chat');
                }).catch(function(error){
                    document.getElementById('1').innerHTML="User Already exists or poor internet";
                })
        })
        }catch{
            console.log("Failed To Authenticate")
        }   
    }
    render(){
        const paper={
            display:'flex',
            flexDirection:'column',
            alignItems:'center',
            paddingLeft:'10px',
            paddingRight:'10px',
            marginTop:'10px'
        }
        return(
           <Grid  container component="main" className="root">
              <Grid item xs={1} sm={4} md={7} className="image">
                   <div className="leftimage">
                   {this.state.isLoading ? (
                       <div className="viewLoadingProfile">
                           <ReactLoading
                           type={'spin'}
                           color={'#203152'}
                           height={'10%'}
                           width={'10%'}
                           />
                       </div>
                   ): null}
                   </div>
                   </Grid>
               <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} className="loginrightcomponent" elevation={6} >
                 <Card style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'center', width:'100%', boxShadow:"0 5px 5px #808888"}}>
                     <Link to="/">
                         <button class="btnhome">
                             <i class="fa fa-home"><span>Go to Home</span></i>
                         </button>
                     </Link>
                 </Card>
                 <div style={paper}>
                     <form style={{marginTop:'50px',width:'100%'}} noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                         <TextField
                         variant="outlined"
                         margin="normal"
                         required
                         fullWidth
                         id="email"
                         label="Email Address"
                         name="email"
                         autoComplete="email"
                         autoFocus
                         onChange={this.handleChange}
                         value={this.state.email}
                         />
                            <TextField
                         variant="outlined"
                         margin="normal"
                         required
                         fullWidth
                         id="password"
                         label="Password:"
                         name="password"
                         type="password"
                         autoComplete="current-password"
                         autoFocus
                         onChange={this.handleChange}
                         value={this.state.password}
                         /> 
                            <TextField
                         variant="outlined"
                         margin="normal"
                         required
                         fullWidth
                         id="name"
                         label="Your Name"
                         name="name"
                         autoComplete="name"
                         autoFocus
                         onChange={this.handleChange}
                         value={this.state.name}
                         />
                         <div>
                             <p style={{color:'grey', fontSize:'15px'}}>Please fill all fields and password should be greater than 6</p>
                         </div>
                         <div className="CenterAliningItems">           
                                 <button className="button1" type="submit">
                                     Signup
                                 </button>     
                            </div>   
                            <div>
                                <p id='1' style={{color:'red'}}></p>
                            </div>  
                     </form>
                 </div>
               </Grid>
           </Grid>

        );
    };
};
export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this line in both catch blocks

```js
this.setState({ isLoading: false });
```

I think an exception is occurring and as you are not altering the loading back to false in the catch blocks, hence it keeps showing the loading screen